# php soap wont create a client?

Tags: php, soap-client

I am trying to connect to my computer running wsdl from a website script, but am having some difficulties :-/

Here is my "very" simple script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo 'Ready 4 soap';
$client  = new SoapClient('http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:8892/SessionManagement?singleWsdl');
echo 'Created a client :-)';
```

For some reason i do not get the second echo "Created a client :-)".

In my console it simply says error status 500!

When copying the http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:8892/SessionManagement?singleWsdl directly into my browser I get the full xml file outcome...

What am I missing since my script stops at the new SoapClient()?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Without knowing the URL, it is hard to guess. Is it possible that the http address is being promoted to https? If so, the certificate might not be trusted and you would have to disable peer verification.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @TheGentleman The domain in which the script is based is not secure (for the same reason). The "url" I trying to reach is the public IP address in which the computer with the wsdl api is located.

Comment: This is older but might be something to look at, apparently the soapclient has had trouble with non-standard ports in the past: https://gist.github.com/jferrao/bd7941e5dd50e271a52a